# Remove duplicated combination in array based on index

Tags: javascript

I have the following data array:

```
const data = [
  {
    value: [
      'a',
      'b',
      'a',
      'a'
    ]
  },
  {
    value: [
      'c',
      'c',
      'd',
      'c'
    ]
  }
];
```

So there's is 4 combination here based on index:
combination 1 : a - c (index 0 in each value arrays)
combination 2 : b - c (index 1 in each value arrays)
combination 3 : a - d (index 2 in each value arrays)
combination 4 : a - c (index 3 in each value arrays)

As you can see the first and the last combinations are the same, so i want to remove the second occurrence from each array, the result should be:

```
    [
        {
        value: [
          'a',
          'b',
          'a'
        ]
      },
      {
        value: [
          'c',
          'c',
          'd'
        ]
      }
  ]
```

Comment: Is your array always of length 2? Are the values always strings?

Comment: @JanStránský no it can be of any length, and the values are always strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the `values` arrays from both objects to form an array which looks like:

```
["a-c", "b-c", ...]
```

As these are now strings, you can turn this array into a Set using `new Set()`, which will remove all duplicate occurrences. You can then turn this set back into an array which you can then use `.reduce()` on to build you array of objects from. For each value you can obtain the list of values by using `.split()` on the `'-'`, and from that, populate your reduced array.

See example below:

```js
const data = [{ value: [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a' ] }, { value: [ 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c' ] } ];

const unq = [...new Set(
  data[0].value.map((_,c)=> data.map(({value})=>value[c]).join('-')) 
)];
const res = unq.reduce((acc, str) => {
  const values = str.split('-');
  values.forEach((value, i) => acc[i].value.push(value));
  return acc;
}, Array.from({length: data.length}, _ => ({value: []})))
console.log(res);
```

Limitations of the above method assume that you won't have a `-` character as your string value. If this is an issue, you can consider using a different delimiter, or find unique values within your array using `.filter()` instead of a Set.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a lookup object for unique pairs of value based with index

Given your input is, below solution could help you

```js
const data = [
  {
    value: ["a", "b", "a", "a"],
  },
  {
    value: ["c", "c", "d", "c"],
  },
]

const lookup = {}

data[0].value.forEach((_, index) => {
  lookup[`${data[0].value[index]}-${data[1].value[index]}`] = true
})

const res = Object.keys(lookup).reduce(
  (acc, key) => {
    const [val1, val2] = key.split("-")
    acc[0].value.push(val1)
    acc[1].value.push(val2)
    return acc
  },
  [{ value: [] }, { value: [] }]
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a two step solution with a generator function and a single pass.

```js
const data = [ { value: [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a' ] }, { value: [ 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', ] } ];

const zipDataValues = function* (data) {
  const iterators = data.map(item => item.value[Symbol.iterator]())
  let iterations = iterators.map(iter => iter.next())
  while (iterations.some(iteration => !iteration.done)) {
    yield iterations.map(iteration => iteration.value)
    iterations = iterators.map(iter => iter.next())
  }
}

const filterOutDuplicateCombos = function (values) {
  const combosSet = new Set(),
    resultData = [{ value: [] }, { value: [] }]
  for (const [valueA, valueB] of values) {
    const setKey = [valueA, valueB].join('')
    if (combosSet.has(setKey)) {
      continue
    }
    combosSet.add(setKey)
    resultData[0].value.push(valueA)
    resultData[1].value.push(valueB)
  }
  return resultData
}

console.log(
  filterOutDuplicateCombos(zipDataValues(data))
) // [ { value: [ 'a', 'b', 'a' ] }, { value: [ 'c', 'c', 'd' ] } ]
```

Here is a reference on [generators and iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Answer (score 0):

Filter combinations + sorting by the first occurrence:

```js
const data = [{
  value: ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
},{
  value: ['c', 'c', 'd', 'c']
}];

var res = {}, i, t;

for (i = 0; i < data[0].value.length; ++i) {
  res[data[0].value[i]] = res[data[0].value[i]] || {};
  res[data[0].value[i]][data[1].value[i]] = true;
}

data[0].value = [];
data[1].value = [];

for (i in res) {
  for (t in res[i]) {
    data[0].value[data[0].value.length] = i;  
    data[1].value[data[1].value.length] = t;  
  }
}

console.log(data);
```